# changing text colour of LI elements

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS Menu which i have had some help with getting sorted, it nearly works as i would like.

i just want to be able to change the text colour on LI hover and also the sub menu seems to be displaying more to the right when it should be directly underneath

CSS:

```
.menu-my-integra-container {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#menu-my-integra, ul.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu-my-integra > li {
    float:left;    
    display: block;
    margin-right:0px;
    position:relative;
    background:#F36F25;
    padding:8px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menu-my-integra > li:hover {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color:#F36F25;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#menu-my-integra li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
    background:#F36F25;
}
ul.sub-menu li {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    float:none;
    padding:5px;
}

ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    color:#F36F25;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    float:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2u21366/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the texts color to the parents:

```
#menu-my-integra li > a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Add `left: 0;` to `ul.sub-menu` to align your sub-menu to the left.

```
ul.sub-menu {
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: excellent - ive sorted the sub menu alignment. thank you. i want the menu to have white text and on hover the background changes to white and the text changes to oragne and the same for the sub menu, how can i do this and also keep the parent item colours when hovering on the sub menu

Comment: ive updated my answer, by removing the `>` you should be able to inherit all colors needed, no just add it to your css and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You color attribute needs to point to the anchor tag rather than the list tag. The colour choice is being overwritten by the default browser style. You need a more direct style path. The following CSS will colour your list as

```
.menu-item a{
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
   color:#F36F25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css file

```html
<body class="news">
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial #1@@</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="about"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News #2@@@</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

```html
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}

/*******************************************
   Style menu for larger screens

   Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
   or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: prefer that file you can get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Your submenu is not properly positioned. You're missing `left: 0;`. That should fix the positioning.

```
   ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
}
```

In regards to hover color

```
a:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Ofcourse I used !important cause I don't understand which color you actually want to change.